# Single query to search in several tables and generate 1 result

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, query-optimization

I'm trying to create a power search using AJAX, that looks for results in 3 different tables and returns the answer in a single table. I have accomplished this by adding 3 calls to my database (one per table), but I feel that this is not optimal.

Users will be typing in a search field and I send what they type to a database using AJAX. This example is as simple as possible to make it easier to be understood.

**Example:**
*User Input*: test.

AJAX call:

```
SELECT 'User' AS table, f_name AS `name`, city FROM people WHERE f_name LIKE '%test%';
SELECT 'Company' AS table, `name`, city FROM companies WHERE `name` LIKE '%test%';
SELECT 'Store' AS table, `name`, city FROM stores WHERE `name` LIKE '%test%';
```

I am not explaining how I generate the table form the ajax call, because that part is solved. What I currently do in PHP is:

```
$sql = SELECT .... FROM people ....;
$res = mysqli...
while($row = mysqli_fetch...) {
   echo "<tr><td>{$row[table]}</td>...."

$sql = SELECT .... FROM companies ....;
$res = mysqli...
while($row = mysqli_fetch...) {
   echo "<tr><td>{$row[table]}</td>...."

$sql = SELECT .... FROM stores ....;
$res = mysqli...
while($row = mysqli_fetch...) {
   echo "<tr><td>{$row[table]}</td>...."
```

Result:

```
+--------------+-------+------+
| table        | name  | city |
+--------------+-------+------+
| User         | test1 | 13   |
| User         | test2 | 25   |
| Company      | testc | 13   |
| Store        | stest | 33   |
+--------------+-------+------+
```

Is there an easier way to achieve this, using fewer HTTP requests? Perhaps using a view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose this could simply be a comment but I can't comment so: why not use `UNION`?

```
SELECT 'User' AS table, f_name AS `name`, city FROM people WHERE f_name LIKE '%test%'
UNION
SELECT 'Company' AS table, `name`, city FROM companies WHERE `name` LIKE '%test%'
UNION
SELECT 'Store' AS table, `name`, city FROM stores WHERE `name` LIKE '%test%'
```

That would give you exactly your result but with just one query-string.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't knew about that function, I was trying with JOIN but obviously it didn't work.

Comment: Quick note if somebody else reads this answer: remove the " ; " between individual queries.